autosave pdf copy of any spreadsheet i save
I'm a webdev so I'm no stranger to code, but I never use VBA. I wrote a macro that I thought would automatically save any .xslx as a pdf (in addition to the .xslx) in the same directory. Here's the code
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFileName As String

    myPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    myFileName = ThisWorkbook.Name

    ' Remove the .xlsx extension from the file name
    myFileName = Left(myFileName, InStrRev(myFileName, ".") - 1)

    ' Save as PDF in the same directory
    ThisWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=myPath & "\" & myFileName & ".pdf"
End Sub


"automatically save any .xslx as a pdf" An xlsx file doesn't contain macros, so where exactly is this code?  Are you trying to capture this event at the Application level?

I obviously meant xlsm lol.

@TimWilliams Actually come to think of it. I mean xltm. Well the macro will be saved in an xltm, but then when I save I will save a normal spreadsheet

Create a new file by opening an xltm file and then save it as an xlsx file. The code in the new file works well until you CLOSE the xlsx file. The code is removed by Excel when closing xlsx files.

That's perfect. Pretty much exactly what I would need it to do because I usually keep the file open until it's been approved, at which point no more changes are needed. Now if the code would only work.


Your code looks fine. Since it's a workbook event code, it should be placed in the ThisWorkbook module.



btw, Adding a timestamp to the filename would be a good idea to avoid overwriting output PDF files.

    ' Save as PDF in the same directory
    ThisWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myPath & "\" & myFileName & Format(Now, "_yyyy.MM.dd_hh.mm.ss") & ".pdf"


This is identical to my code. Minus the timestamp obviously. Why do you recommend it? Because these are files for work and our file naming system includes timestamps and is pretty robust.
Also I didn't include the 'Option Explicit' bit. What does that do? Also, maybe I'm messing up some steps outside of this. I'm then going and saving the file as a xltm. Then from there I should be able to save that template as an xlsx and still have the macro trigger, right?

The crucial point is ensuring that the event code is stored in the correct module. It won't work if it's accidentally placed in a standard module or a SheetX module. I'll retract the answer if this isn't the cause of your issue.

If you only need to keep the final copy for each file, then you don't need the timestamp in the filename. It depends on your work scenario, so there's no right or wrong approach here.

Okay that's what I thought you were getting at. Yeah we only ever keep one copy of the file, If changes are made we overwrite
